# Controlar cuantos días dentro de dos fechas perteneces a dos listas con SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedure

La problemática es la siguiente:

Debo poder identificar cuantos días dentro de dos fechas determinadas son iguales a las fechas existentes en otra tabla **`FechasEspeciales`** pre-cargada, así como también saber si dentro de estas dos fechas se paso por el fin de semana. Y de esto sacar las totalidad de los días.

Por ejemplo si la fecha inicial fuera el martes 07/05/2019 y la final el lunes 13/05/2019 , y suponiendo que dentro de la tabla **`FechasEspeciales.Fecha`** tengo los días (08/05/2019 y 10/05/2019), el resultado que debería obtener seria 4 días: 2 por las dos fechas existentes en la tabla y 2 mas por estar el fin de semana entre las fechas establecidas.

Esto lo debo poder realizar con SQL Server, ya que es parte de un procedimiento almacenado que se ejecutará diariamente.

Esta funcionalidad es la que me estaría faltando, no se me ha ocurrido como realizarla de forma eficiente. Gracias por su tiempo desde ya.

Comment: Pero que es lo que tienes al momento, agrega tu query en tu pregunta y especifica el error o duda al respecto

Comment: No te apures tanto por la eficiencia. Lo importante es que funcione, utiliza lo que ya tienes. La eficiencia es algo que se ve después, y se trabaja sobre la solución inicial que tengas. Un saludo.

Comment: Revisa si te sirve: 'select * from tabla where tabla.fecha not in (select FechasEspeciales.fecha from FechasEspeciales) and DATEPART(dw,tabla.fecha)<>7 and DATEPART(dw,tabla.fecha)<>1'. Te recomiendo que investigues DATEPART.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como bien dice @juanchete primero veamos la funcionalidad. Como no conozco la estructura de tus tablas no puedo orientar mucho en ese sentido.

Pero puedes generar una ventana de tiempo y evaluar si cumple con las condiciones que indicas. Te dejo el siguiente ejemplo acumulando variables en una evaluación pasando por un ciclo `WHILE`

```
SET NOCOUNT ON 

DECLARE @tmp TABLE ([FechasEspeciales] date)

INSERT INTO @tmp VALUES ('2019-05-08')
INSERT INTO @tmp VALUES ('2019-05-10')

DECLARE @FechaInicio date,
        @FechaFin date,
        @CntDias int

SET @FechaInicio = '2019-05-07'
SET @FechaFin = '2019-05-13'
SET @CntDias = 0

WHILE @FechaInicio <= @FechaFin
BEGIN

    SET @CntDias = @CntDias + IIF(DATEPART(WEEKDAY,@FechaInicio) IN (6,7) OR @FechaInicio IN (SELECT [FechasEspeciales] FROM @tmp),1,0)

    SET @FechaInicio = DATEADD(day,1,@FechaInicio)
END

PRINT @CntDias
```

Answer (score 1):

A mi manera de ver, una manera eficiente de determinar los días, sería, primero, calcular los días *hábiles* que han transcurrido entre ambas fechas y a este cálculo restarle la cuenta de los días especiales que tenes registrados en la tabla.

Así que, vamos paso por paso:

## Cálculo de días calendario:

Comenzamos con lo básico. La función `datediff` nos va a calcular la diferencia de días entre dos fechas. Es importante aquí tener en cuenta que el cálculo dado no es *totalmente inclusuvo*. Por ejemplo, `datediff('20190507', '20190508')` retorna el valor de 1 día. Si queremos un valor totalmente inclusivo, debemos sumarle 1. Esto va a ser así si, por ejemplo, estamos calculando los días trabajados por una persona, y no los días transcurridos entre una fecha y otra. De acá en adelante, la solución supondrá que estamos haciendo un cálculo totalmente inclusivo.

```
declare @FechaIni date = '20190507';
declare @FechaFin date = '20190513';

select DATEDIFF(day, @FechaIni, @FechaFin) DiasCalendario;
```

Retorna:

```
DiasCalendario
-----------
6

(1 row affected)
```

## Cálculo de días hábiles:

Vamos a suponer que trabajamos de lunes a viernes, y por tanto, nos interesa *sacar* de la cuenta de días, los fines de semana (2 días por semana). Este cálculo es simple si encontramos la forma de saber cuántos fines de semana han transcurrido entre dos fechas. Por suerte, si a la misma función ´datediff´ le pasamos el parámetro `week`, para darnos el resultado SQL Server calcula la diferencia entre el número de semana de ambas fechas y no basado en el número de días. Por lo tanto, sabremos cuántos domingos hay entre las dos fechas. Podemos entonces, restar este número multiplicado por dos de los días calendario para saber los días hábiles.

```
declare @FechaIni date = '20190507';
declare @FechaFin date = '20190513';

select   DATEDIFF(day, @FechaIni, @FechaFin) + 1  --días calendario
       - DATEDIFF(WEEK, @FechaIni, @FechaFin) * 2 --fines de semana
       DiasHabiles
;
```

Esto nos retorna:

```
DiasHabiles
-----------
5

(1 row affected)
```

Para completar esta parte de la respuesta, la fórmula de los días hábiles fallaría si alguna de las fechas es domingo, el cálculo completo que funciona para cualquier fecha sería:

```
declare @FechaIni date = '20190507';
declare @FechaFin date = '20190513';

select   datediff(day, @FechaIni, @FechaFin) + 1  --días calendario
       - datediff(week, @FechaIni, @FechaFin) * 2 
       - case when (datepart(dw, @FechaIni) + @@datefirst + 5) % 7 = 6 then 1 else 0 end 
       + case when (datepart(dw, @FechaFin) + @@datefirst + 5) % 7 = 6 then 1 else 0 end  --Fines de semana
       DiasHabiles
;
```

Que sigue retornando, en las fechas de ejemplo, el mismo valor.

## Resta de días especiales

Finalmente, suponiendo que tenemos una tabla de días especiales, que voy a simular con un CTE, finalmente le restamos la cantidad de ocurrencias de días especiales entre ambas fechas.

La selección es sencilla, algo como esto hará el trabajo:

```
select count(1) from DiasEspeciales where Fecha between @FechaIni and @FechaFin
```

Ya integrado en el código, quedaría así<sup>1</sup>:

```
declare @FechaIni date = '20190507';
declare @FechaFin date = '20190513';

with
DiasEspeciales as (
          select cast('20190101' as date) Fecha
union all select '20190508'
union all select '20190510'
union all select '20191225'
)
select   datediff(day, @FechaIni, @FechaFin) + 1  --días calendario
       - datediff(week, @FechaIni, @FechaFin) * 2 
       - case when (datepart(dw, @FechaIni) + @@datefirst + 5) % 7 = 6 then 1 else 0 end 
       + case when (datepart(dw, @FechaFin) + @@datefirst + 5) % 7 = 6 then 1 else 0 end  -- fines de semana
       - coalesce((select count(1) from DiasEspeciales where Fecha between @FechaIni and @FechaFin), 0)  -- días especiales
       DiasLaborales
;
```

Lo cual nos arroja el siguiente resultado:

```
DiasLaborales
-------------
3

(1 row affected)
```

## Comprobación

Dado que el resultado obtenido es de 3 días, y no de 4 como especificas en la pregunta, haremos la comprobación para ver si estamos bien en la respuesta:

```
Fecha         Día         Especial     Contador
============  ==========  ===========  ===========
07/mayo/2019  Martes      NO           1
08/mayo/2019  Miércoles   SI
09/mayo/2019  Jueves      NO           2
10/mayo/2019  Viernes     SI
11/mayo/2019  Sabado
12/mayo/2019  Domingo
13/mayo/2019  Lunes       NO           3
```

Como podemos ver, la respuesta de **3 días** es correcta, y no la de 4.

## Advertencia

En la tabla de fechas especiales no debiera haber fechas de fines de semana. Si cabe la posibilidad, habría que excluir esas fechas, si no esos días se van a restar dos veces. Esa mejora que, en mi opinión, debiera tener un sistema hecho para el mundo real, queda como ejercicio para el lector.

<sup>1</sup>: He agregado intencionalmente un par de fechas más al CTE de fechas especiales, solo por hacer más completo el ejemplo.